# Map a value based on two conditions in two dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My problem is to not get bogged down in too bloated code for what I need.
It is about getting points for riders in a particular race for a particular team. I need to read two condition columns in one df1, compare them with the same two condition columns in df2 and if both True, get value from df1.

The conditions to be the same are the TEAM and the RACE, the PLAYER should be matched to POINTS based on those.

I do not necessarily need to have the values substitutes or mapped in any of the existing dataframes, perhaps even creating a df3 would be more convenient.

Here is df1 and df2:

```
players = ['X_ER', 'Y_ER', 'Z_ER', 'W_ER', 'X_ER', 'Y_ER']
races = ['RACE_1','RACE_1','RACE_1','RACE_1', 'RACE_2', 'RACE_2']
points = [100, 50, 20, 10, 50, 100]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'PLAYER':players,
                    'RACE':races,
                    'POINTS':points})

teams = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'AAA', 'BBB']
races = ['RACE_1','RACE_1','RACE_1','RACE_1', 'RACE_2', 'RACE_2']
player1 = ['X_ER', 'W_ER', 'Y_ER', 'W_ER', 'X_ER', 'Y_ER']
player2 = ['Z_ER', 'Y_ER', 'D_ER', 'K_ER', 'Y_ER', 'X_ER']

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'TEAM':teams,
                    'RACE':races,
                    'PLAYER1':player1,
                    'PLAYER2':player2})
```

Outputs of df1 and df2:

```
    PLAYER  RACE    POINTS
0   X_ER    RACE_1  100
1   Y_ER    RACE_1  50
2   Z_ER    RACE_1  20
3   W_ER    RACE_1  10
4   X_ER    RACE_2  50
5   Y_ER    RACE_2  100


    TEAM    RACE    PLAYER1 PLAYER2
0   AAA     RACE_1  X_ER    Z_ER
1   BBB     RACE_1  W_ER    Y_ER
2   CCC     RACE_1  Y_ER    D_ER
3   DDD     RACE_1  W_ER    K_ER
4   AAA     RACE_2  X_ER    Y_ER
5   BBB     RACE_2  Y_ER    X_ER
```

And the result should be something like this.

```
teams = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'AAA', 'BBB']
races = ['RACE_1','RACE_1','RACE_1','RACE_1', 'RACE_2', 'RACE_2']
result1 = [100, 10, 50, 10, 50, 100]
result2 = [20, 50, 0, 0, 100, 50]

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'TEAM':teams,
                    'RACE':races,
                    'RESULT1':result1,
                    'RESULT2':result2})
```

Output of d3:

```
    TEAM    RACE    RESULT1     RESULT2
0   AAA     RACE_1  100         20
1   BBB     RACE_1  10          50
2   CCC     RACE_1  50          0
3   DDD     RACE_1  10          0
4   AAA     RACE_2  50          100
5   BBB     RACE_2  100         50
```

As I have said, no specific end-method in mind, I am leaning making a third df with only the columns of interest instead of .map() or lambda, the end result doesn't have to be 1:1 with the df3 example.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done with just 2 merges and a final column selection:

```
df2 \
    .merge(
        df1,
        how="left",
        left_on=["RACE", "PLAYER1"], right_on=["RACE", "PLAYER"], suffixes=[None, "1"]
    ) \
    .drop(["PLAYER1"], axis=1) \ # to avoid duplicated names while merging
    .merge(
        df1,
        how="left",
        left_on=["RACE", "PLAYER2"], right_on=["RACE", "PLAYER"], suffixes=["1", "2"]
    ) \
    [["TEAM", "RACE", "POINTS1", "POINTS2"]] \
    .fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
  TEAM    RACE  POINTS1  POINTS2
0  AAA  RACE_1      100     20.0
1  BBB  RACE_1       10     50.0
2  CCC  RACE_1       50      0.0
3  DDD  RACE_1       10      0.0
4  AAA  RACE_2       50    100.0
5  BBB  RACE_2      100     50.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Just perform a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for each column:

```
cols = ['PLAYER1', 'PLAYER2']

df3 = df2.drop(columns=cols)
for col in cols:
    df3[col.replace('PLAYER', 'RESULT')] = (df2.rename(columns={col: 'PLAYER'})
                                               .merge(df1, how='left')['POINTS']
                                               .fillna(0).convert_dtypes()
                                           )
```

Or [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and `merge`:

```
tmp = df2.melt(['TEAM', 'RACE'], value_name='PLAYER',
               ignore_index=False)

df3 = (df2[['TEAM', 'RACE']]
       .join(tmp.merge(df1, how='left').set_index(tmp.index)
                .pivot(columns='variable', values='POINTS')
                .fillna(0).convert_dtypes()
                .rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('PLAYER', 'RESULT'))
            )
      )
```

Output:

```
  TEAM    RACE  RESULT1  RESULT2
0  AAA  RACE_1      100       20
1  BBB  RACE_1       10       50
2  CCC  RACE_1       50        0
3  DDD  RACE_1       10        0
4  AAA  RACE_2       50      100
5  BBB  RACE_2      100       50
```